# Shiny Generate a new point and delete the old one on click

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I would like to add a point when the user click on a plot and delete the previous one. My idea was to generate a new plot with only the new point but the coordinate of the click immediately change when generating the new plot.

Here is a simple example of what I'm trying to do :

```
library(shiny)
ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Plot points"),
  sidebarPanel(textOutput("text")),
  mainPanel(plotOutput("points_plot",click="click_p"))
)

server <- function(session, input, output) {

  output$points_plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(5,5)
    points(input$click_p$x,input$click_p$y)
  })

  output$text=renderText({
paste(input$click_p$x,input$click_p$y)  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

How can i keep the coordinate of my new point ?

Or maybe it's possible to use something like the leafletProxy function from the Leaflet package ?

Comment: This code here from the demo might help you (using ggplot): https://gallery.shinyapps.io/106-plot-interaction-exclude/

Comment: Thank you, the key was to use a reactiveValues